# Creating a maze-like game with links between objects

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm writing a text-based RPG that will create its own cave system according to the following rules:

1. It must randomly generate links
2. One cave may only link to another once
3. Each cave must have four links in total

This is what I have so far:

```
import random

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.caves = []

    def main(self):
        self.createCaves()
        Caves.setLinks(self)

    def createCaves(self):
        self.caves.append(StartCave())
        number_of_caves = random.randrange(10)+5
        for cave in range(1,((number_of_caves) if number_of_caves%2 != 0 else (number_of_caves+1))):
            self.caves.append(NormCave())
        self.caves.append(EndCave())

class Caves(Game):
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = 3
        self.links = []

    def setLinks(self):
        possible = self.caves
        while True:
            for cave in possible:
                while len(cave.links) != 4:
                    link = possible[random.randint(0,(len(possible)-1))]
                    while len(link.links) == 4 or link == cave or cave in link.links:
                        link = possible[random.randint(0,(len(possible)-1))]
                    cave.links.append(link)
                possible.remove(cave)

class StartCave(Caves):
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = 3
        self.links = []

class EndCave(Caves):
    pass
#    def __init__(self):
#        pass

class NormCave(Caves):
    pass
#    def __init__(self):
#        pass

B = Game()
B.main()
```

After so many iterations of the `setLinks` function, the array called `possible` only contains one cave, so it cannot create any more links and the cave left has no links to any other cave. What it should be doing is creating 4 random links between caves, storing these links in its `links` array then moving onto the next cave that has fewer than 4 links.

Comment: If you mean your code isn't currently working, please cut it down to a [mcve]. If you mean you want help implementing additional functionality, then that's off-topic for SO.

Comment: Are links between caves unidirectional or bidirectional? Are you sure your constraints are mathematically satisfiable?

Comment: I assume they are uni-directional as I'm pretty sure they can interact with each other but honestly I don't know python well enough to say. I think they are, that's why I'm asking for help :-)

Comment: Isa's got it. Your checks to see if the other end of the link already has 4 links are assuming the links are made both ways, but you're only actually creating them one way.

Comment: The question was about the specifications of your program, not what it does in its current state. Do you *want* your links to be unidirectional or do they have to be bidirectional? This will change the implementation. Also, are the links a fixed "4 per cave" or "at least one, up to 4" ? The former is actually quite complex (try picturing it in 3D)

Comment: It's  hard to help when even you don't seem to know how your program works, but I suspect `possible = self.caves` and the `for cave in possible: ... possible.remove(cave)` are not doing what you think.

Comment: Thank you that's perfect! I know exactly what I've done wrong, I need to make the caves bi-directional and I can fix it. And yes they have to be exactly 4 per cave, I know there's a set of algorithms that can do this but I'm not sure what they're called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple brute-force algorithm. We use sets to hold the links for each cave. The `make_links` function tries to assign 4 random bidirectional links to each cave. If it fails, it returns `None` and we simply call it again until we get a valid cave system.

```
from random import seed, choice

def make_caves(num):
    caves = None
    while caves is None:
        caves = make_links(num)
    return caves

def make_links(num):
    numrange = range(num)
    rset = set(numrange)

    caves = [set() for _ in numrange]
    for i in numrange:
        others = list(rset - set([i]) - caves[i])
        while len(caves[i]) < 4:
            if not others:
                return None
            x = choice(others)
            others.remove(x)
            if len(caves[x]) == 4:
                continue
            caves[x].add(i)
            caves[i].add(x)
    return caves

# Test

seed(13)
num = 12
numrange = range(num)

caves = make_caves(num)

for i in numrange:
    print(i, caves[i])
print()

for i in numrange:
    row = ''.join(['* ' if j in caves[i] else '. ' for j in numrange])
    print('{:>2} {}'.format(i, row))
```

**typical output**

```
0 {9, 3, 5, 6}
1 {8, 9, 4, 5}
2 {9, 11, 4, 6}
3 {0, 8, 10, 5}
4 {1, 2, 9, 7}
5 {0, 1, 3, 11}
6 {0, 10, 2, 11}
7 {8, 10, 11, 4}
8 {1, 10, 3, 7}
9 {0, 1, 2, 4}
10 {8, 3, 6, 7}
11 {2, 5, 6, 7}

 0 . . . * . * * . . * . . 
 1 . . . . * * . . * * . . 
 2 . . . . * . * . . * . * 
 3 * . . . . * . . * . * . 
 4 . * * . . . . * . * . . 
 5 * * . * . . . . . . . * 
 6 * . * . . . . . . . * * 
 7 . . . . * . . . * . * * 
 8 . * . * . . . * . . * . 
 9 * * * . * . . . . . . . 
10 . . . * . . * * * . . . 
11 . . * . . * * * . . . .
```

There are 4 asterisks in each row and each column of the grid, which demonstrates that we have 4 bidirectional links for each cave.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an matrix (n, m) where each element is a possible cave. This way every cave will have 4 neighbors except the caves on the "borders".

Considering you are on the cave (i, j), your neighbors are (i-1, j), (i+1, j), (i, j-1) and (i, j+1).

And for encapsulation, a CaveContainer object would be good to have. This way your implementation of the way caves are generated is not linked to the rest of the code.

Some good tutorial about code architecture:
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Comment: The matrix is a good idea but the links must not be in a grid, they must be random. Thank you for the cave container object, I'll be sure to implement it

Comment: How do you ensure geographical consistency ?